# Is there a simple way of comparing generic static Dart types (DartType)?

Tags: dart, types, code-generation, analyzer, visitor-pattern

Using a SimpleElementVisitor (from Dart package [source_gen](https://pub.dev/packages/source_gen)) I am trying to process an input file say *player_input.dart*:

```
class _PlayerInput {
  final id = Property<int>();
  final name = Property<String>();
  final int teamId;
}
```

to generate a model say *player.dart*:

```
class Player {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  const Player({this.id, this.name});
}
```

While iterating through the fields of `_PlayerInput` I would like to filter out elements of type `Property<int>, Property<bool>, Property<String>.`

**Is there a straightforward way of comparing (generic) static DartTypes?** 
Something along the lines of:

```
if (element.type == (A static type corresponding to Property<int> || ... ){
  properties.add(element);

}
```

For now, I am using a [TypeChecker](https://pub.dev/documentation/source_gen/latest/source_gen/TypeChecker-class.html), in a rather convoluted way. See method `_addProperty()` below.

```
class _PlayerVisitor extends SimpleElementVisitor {
  List<FieldElement> fields = [];
  List<FieldElement> properties = [];

  static var _propertyChecker = TypeChecker.fromRuntime(Property);
  static var _argumentChecker = TypeChecker.any([
    TypeChecker.fromRuntime(int),
    TypeChecker.fromRuntime(bool),
    TypeChecker.fromRuntime(String),
  ]);

  _addProperty(FieldElement element) {
    // Check if element is [Property<Type>].
    if (!_propertyChecker.isAssignableFromType(element.type)) return;

    // Validate type argument of Property<Type>
    var propertyType = typeArgumentsOf(element.type).first;
    if (_argumentChecker.isExactlyType(propertyType)) {
        properties.add(element);
    } else {
        // Invalid type argument of generic class Property<Type>.
        throw ModelGeneratorException(
            '''Variable ${element.name} has unsupported type: Property<$propertyType>.
          Valid types are: Property<int>, Property<String>, Property<bool>''');
    }
  }

  @override
  visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    fields.add(element);
    _addProperty(element);
  }

  List<DartType> typeArgumentsOf(DartType type) {
    return type is ParameterizedType ? type.typeArguments : const [];
  }


}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `isDartCoreInt`?

ie:

```dart
bool isRaw(element) => element.type.isDartCoreInt || 
  element.type.isDartCoreBool
```

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, the question is about generic types. In the example I mentioned above the runtime time of the object would be `Property<int>` or `Property<String>`. In other words, the generic type is `Property` and `String` or `int` are the type arguments.

Comment: yeah, I understood it. No matter if it is a generic type or not in the end it is a DartType, thus, you can use isDartCoreInt, in your case: ```propertyType.isDartCoreInt``` instead of ```_argumentChecker.isExactlyType(propertyType)```. What I did was a ```isCore``` extension method that calls all those ```isDartCore``` stuff